# How to hide a div if validation summary is available in javascript/Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

How to hide a div if validation summary is available in javascript/Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var validationSummary = $('#<%= this.ValidationSummary.ClientID %>');
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');

if (validationSummary.length || validationSummary.is(':visible')) {
    myDiv.hide();
}
```

the cause for `.is(':visible')`is, that i don't know if an empty validationSummary renders the html-tags either or not. if not, you can leave out the `.is()`-check

Answer (score 2):

```
if(yourCondition){
  $("div#mydiv").hide()
}
```

what is validation summary?

Comment: Usually a validation summary is a div or block that contains all the error messages generated by a group of validation controls in some kind of list form.

Comment: IIRC, the validation summary is in a div.  mkoryak's solution should work.

Comment: Set the validation summary's cssclass to say zzz.  Then you can do mkoryak's sol'n.  if (".zzz") { ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use the HeaderText property to clean the HTML from inner ValidationSummary, seek in console for your content and you can see what change to erase.

I use this: create an element and call javascript function

```
ValidationSummary ID="vsGeral" runat="server" HeaderText="create element and call the HTML clean function destroy "

 var validationSummary = $('[id$=vsGeral]');

 if (validationSummary.length || validationSummary.is(':visible')) {

     function destroy() {

         $("[id$=vsGeral]").html("");

     }

 }
```